# why the index is starting from 10 even though i had given in { for int i =0;}

Tags: java, string, eclipse

Java print wrong value during the concatination of integer with '\n' escape character in: `System.out.print(i + '\n');`

```
package demo;

import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Demo {

    static void fun() {

        System.out.println("this is my first code");
    }

    static void fun2() {
        int a, b, c;

        a = 20;
        b = 3;
        c = a + b;
        System.out.println(c);
    }

    public static void fun3() {
        String c = "dsdfjdsldw";// its adding 10 more char here why??so??
        char a[] = { 's', 'e', 'd', 'e', 'd', 'd', 'd' };
        System.out.print("string:" + (c) + '\n');
        System.out.print("char:" + new String(a) + '\n');

        for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++) {
            char e = c.charAt(i);
            System.out.print(i + '\n');
            System.out.print(c.length() + '\n');
            System.out.print('\n');
            System.out.print("char at->" + i + '\n');
            System.out.print("index is->" + e + '\n');
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fun();
        fun2();
        fun3();

    }

}
```

*******************OUTPUT*******************

```
this is my first code
 23 
string:dsdfjdsldw 
char:sededdd 
1020 //here the index start with 10:why?
char at->0 
index is->d 1120
```

Answer (score 3):

The character '\n' is the problem, when you use '+' operator with '\n' it takes ASCII equivalent  value of '\n', that is 10 , please use "\n" instead of '\n',

Comment: Or use `println` to add the newline.

Answer (score 0):

Are you are trying to add a to c

Try :

```
String tmp = a.strcat(c);
a =tmp;
```

You could also look at StringBuilder.
There are lots of google examples.  It lets you append, insert and play around with Strings.

Comment: the problem in not there , my concern is with the index value which start with 10 instead of zero